# how do i create a text file using the list that is given

Tags: text-files

I need to create a text file called Names_ages.txt using the following list

```
Josh 14   
Lauren 16   
Paul 18  
Mason 15  
Lily 17  
Stephanie 15
```

If anyone can help me and understand how to create one, that would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates a text file from a list:

```
outfile = open("Names_ages.txt",'w')
name_list = ["Josh 14", "Lauren 16", "Paul 18", "Mason 15", "Lily 17", "Stephanie 15"]

outfile.write("\n".join(name_list))
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you, could you mark the answer as the solution please?